# Why is $\left(I - M M^T \right)^{-1} M = M\left(I - M^T M \right)^{-1}$

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

While trying to generalize a certain formula from the scalar case to the matrix case, I came across the following curious observation:

Let $M$ be a real, not necessarily square matrix, then
$$\left(I -  M M^T \right)^{-1} M = M\left(I -  M^T M \right)^{-1}$$
which seems to be true in general. It holds, for example, for this randomly chosen case
$$M=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -1 & 7 & -4 \\
 -1 & 5 & 7 \\
 -4 & 7 & 4 \\
 -2 & -5 & 0 \\
 2 & -1 & -6 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Although numerical examples convinced me that this is true, I do not understand why. Any hints?

Comment: Hint: 2/3=4/6 because 2×6=3×4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More in detail we have that if $M$ is a n-by-m matrix

- $X=I -  MM^T$ is a n-by-n matrix
- $Y=I -  M^T M$ is a m-by-m matrix

and therefore

$$X_{n\times n}^{-1}M_{n\times m}=M_{n\times m}Y_{m\times m}^{-1}$$

$$X_{n\times n}X_{n\times n}^{-1}M_{n\times m}Y_{m\times m}=X_{n\times n}M_{n\times m}Y_{m\times m}^{-1}Y_{m\times m}$$

$$I_{n\times n}M_{n\times m}Y_{m\times m}=X_{n\times n}M_{n\times m}I_{m\times m}$$

$$M_{n\times m}Y_{m\times m}=X_{n\times n}M_{n\times m}$$

that is

$$M \left(I -  M^T M \right) = \left(I -  M M^T \right) M$$

Comment: Gimusi please fix your $X$.

Comment: @Maam Good catch! Thanks, I fix the typo!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Empy2, just multiply both sides with the "denominator" from the other side:
$$\left(I -  M M^T \right)^{-1} M = M\left(I -  M^T M \right)^{-1}$$
$$\iff  M \left(I -  M^T M \right) = \left(I -  M M^T \right) M$$
$$\iff M -  M M^T M = M -  M M^T M$$

Comment: Can you add this to your OP? I believe you know the rules, you have gathered extra credit for answering your own post. That in itself is fine; this extra answer need to go in your original post, and this one should be deleted.

Comment: @Kevin I don't think this is necessary. It's allowed to answer one's own question, and even accept one's own answer (although it doesn't bring any reputation). See also [this Meta question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20972/what-is-se-etiquette-when-answering-your-own-question).

Comment: @ArnaudD. Oh! I thought answering your own post in this way was against house rules. My mistake. I checked https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer and it is totaly true. I had no idea, Thansk for your clarification and I extend my apologies to Wouter.

Comment: @Wouter My apologies, as you can see above, I am wrong. I accept that. I downvoted this anser on the basis that that you shouldn't answer your own post. I cannot re-upvote as I am locked in. I will, however, check some more of your excellent answers! All the best, Kevin

Comment: @Kevin Just for your information (and perhaps Wouter's), you can retract your vote if the question is edited.